# Setting the width of an element to another element

Tags: angular

I have a search bar and its drop-down suggestions. I would like the dropdown to have the same width as the search bar but the search bars width is dynamic depending on the window size. How can I set the width of the autocomplete dropdown so it dynamically updates to be the width of the search input?

I would like an Angular 2+ solution (I've seen a couple based on JQuery). Seems like a fairly basic question but couldn't find a solution online.

Answer (score 1):

You can track a current width of search bar using the snippet from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084344/8490932

And inject extracted width into `style.width` input of your auto-complete dropdown.