# How to take width of html element in angular2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to take the width of my table and then to use that width for the condition to applying styles dynamically based on width.
Example:

```
div class="nano-table-grid"
    [ngStyle]="{ tableCurrentWidth < 1200px ? 'flex: none; max-width: 75px;'}>
```

I have the problem to take that current width of the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get width of (DOM) Element in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084250/how-to-get-width-of-dom-element-in-angular2)

Comment: with this it is really hard to tell how you are computing/getting the width of that element. If you could post the other code that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div #table class="nano-table-grid"
  [ngStyle]="tableStyle(table.offsetWidth)"></div>
```

```js
tableStyle(tableWidth: number) {
  return tableWidth > 1200 ? {
    display: 'block'
  } : {
    display: 'flex',
    maxWidth: '75px'
  }
}
```

You can instead use `ngClass` as @SachilaRanawaka suggested, both work.

Answer (score 2):

use the `ngClass` by creating a separate style class.

```
.sample{
  flex: none; 
  max-width: 75px;
}

div class="nano-table-grid"  [ngClass]="{'sample':  tableCurrentWidth < 1200px }>
```